# How do I attach an observer to a method without adding code to the method itself?

Tags: ruby, observer-pattern

I'm trying to figure out a way to have a method trigger another method by creating a new Listener class. I'd really like the code to be simplified and not involve adding anything specific to the callback method or the trigger method. Basically, what I'm trying to do is this:

```
def level_up
  level += 1
end

def print_level
  puts "Level Up! (#{level})"
end

notify_level = Listener.new(:level_up, :print_level);
```

What my Listener class is (right now) is this:

```
# Listener.new(attached_to, callbacks)
class Listener
  def initialize(attached_to, function)
    @owner, @callback = attached_to, function
  end

  def owner
    @owner
  end

  def callback
    @callback
  end

  def trigger
    # execute callback manually
    self.method(@owner).call
    self.method(@callback).call
  end
end
```

In order to call both, I need to execute `notify_level.trigger` itself, but what I want is to execute `level_up` and call `print_level`. I know someone will mention something about observers, but I need more than just that. I want to hold fast to DRY. Manually adding observers and listeners to every single method is just terrible, especially since I can't add or remove them with ease.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my original code to be more semantic and so it would make more sense.

```
class Event
  def initialize(event, callback_array = [])
    if callback_array.kind_of? Array
      @callbacks = callback_array
    else
      @callbacks = [callback_array]
    end

    @event = event
  end

  def trigger(*args)

    self.method(@event).call *args

    @callbacks.each{ |callback|
      if callback.instance_of? Event
        callback.trigger *args
      else
        method(callback).call *args
      end
    }
  end

  def add(callback)
    @callbacks.push callback
  end

  def remove(callback)
    @callbacks.delete_at(@callbacks.index(callback) || @callbacks.length)
  end

  def event_name
    @event
  end
end
```

Usage:

```
$infinite_break = 10

def infinite_loop_a(type)
  puts "#{$infinite_break} points of #{type} damage taken"
  $infinite_break -= 1

  if $infinite_break > 0
    $infinite.trigger(type)
  else
    $infinite.remove(:infinite_loop_a)
  end
end

def infinite_loop_b(type)
  puts "player is dealing #{$infinite_break} damage"
end

$infinite = Event.new(:infinite_loop_b, :infinite_loop_a)
$infinite.trigger('fire')
```

Also, I know I'm calling the `infinite_loop_b` inside `infinite_loop_a`, but that's for a specific reason. The `Event` instances can have another `Event` as a callback.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I'm not a big fan of this pattern but this is kind of a fun question so here is my solution. Should work in Ruby 1.9 and greater.

```
module MethodListener
  @@observed_methods = {}

  def method_added(method)
    alias_name = "__#{method}_orig"
    return if method_defined?(alias_name) || method.match(/__.*_orig/)

    alias_method alias_name, method
    define_method(method) do |*args|
      ret = send(alias_name, *args)
      (@@observed_methods[method] || []).each {|callback| send(callback)}
      ret
    end
  end

  def listen(owner, callback)
    (@@observed_methods[owner] ||= []) << callback
  end
end
```

Usage example:

```
class A
  extend MethodListener

  def b(a,b)
    puts "b #{a} #{b}"
    true
  end

  def c
    puts 'c'
  end

  listen :b, :c
end

A.new.b(1,2) # => true
# Prints:
# b 1 2
# c
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, but I already came up with my own solution. One that can pass arguments to the callback too. I'll post it so you can check it out if you want.

Comment: Hmm. Well I cant pretend that my solution is the best idea (it doubles the number of instance methods) but it should be easy to extend it to allow args to be passed to the callback or run a proc. I think its advantage over your alternative is that it will always execute the callback without the need to generate an object. Since you will have to generate a new instance of `Event` or store it to call `trigger` in the future why dont you just define a new method that first calls `infinite_loop_b` and then `infinite_loop_a`?

Comment: It's actually just future proofing the structure of my code. I'm doing it in a specific way. Think of it like this: Player Xyxx equips Sword of Burning Burns that deals 2 fire damage whenever it hits an opponent. I want to create a new Event whenever the player equips the sword, then destroy it whenever I unequip it. Honestly, the reason why I'm hesitant about your answer is because you use things like `alias_name = "__#{method}_orig"` and `return if method_defined?(alias_name) || method.match(/__.*_orig/)` which seem like it would run slowly.

Comment: Use whatever solution you are most comfortable with of course :) The condition and alias name are only evaluated when a method is added to the class, so unless you are dynamically adding methods to classes at runtime it will only have an effect at startup.